# Rigid body pile of objects not settling

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm trying to apply the ideas of [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQ9VmCN2EsE) [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVYYMG3QVY) tutorials to a different (non-donut) object.  I want to drop the 100 or so objects onto the ground to form an irregular pile of the objects.

My object is a single mesh, all extruded from a cube, no joined objects.

I've made an array of them in x and y, making sure to keep them separated and not touching each other.

I've applied the arrays, then selected all the objects, gone to Edit Mode and pressed <kbd>p</kbd> to separate - selecting “by loose parts”

Applied a rigid body, type = passive to the ground plane, and "active" to the falling objects.

I've tried the objects at 1kg and 0.1kg, and adjusting the friction on the active and passive objects, but I get the same issue - the objects are swirling into a kind of weird vortex?

https://youtu.be/3ivJlWRnzx4

Answer (score 2):

Argh - I forgot to "Set Origin" to "Geometry" for each of the falling objects.  Hope this helps someone else